# Accessing a variable from another file that's in a loop in Python

Tags: python, function, loops, variables

I have a file that is reading measurements in the main. This function is in a while True loop. Inside this loop I want to change a variable as it goes through the process. No problems with setting that up. The issue I have is accessing this variable from another file.

File 1:

```
def main()
    print("obtaining token")
    obtainnewtoken()

    while True:
        print("******LOOP****** + str(i)")
        (read measurement stuff ) 
        postTrue = True
        return postTrue
```

File 2:

```
from File1 import *

newPostTrue = main()

def codechecker():
    print(newPostTrue)
```

When I run both files simultaneously File2 just runs the main of File1. How Do I access a variable that is in the loop in another file?

Also I would still like to run both files separately. This setup is temporary.

Comment: Can you format the code properly, mainly the indentation?

Comment: it was an example of the code. I can sort it out for you

Comment: Have you set up pythonpath in environment variable?

Comment: yeah i've done that

Comment: Both are in same directory??

Comment: yes they both are

Answer (score 0):

You can use something called as generators which will "Yield" a value once, and then you can use the next() function to get the next value from the generator.

File_1:

```
def Generator():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print("******LOOP******" + str(i))
        i += 1
        yield i
```

File_2:

```
from File_1 import *

newPostTrue = Generator()


def codechecker():
    j = next(newPostTrue)
    while (j < 10):
        print(j)
        j = next(newPostTrue)


codechecker()
```

Comment: My plan was to run both programs separately which I should have mentioned. This works but not the way I need it to. I will clarify in my question.